# Prestashop payment in webview Android

Tags: android, prestashop, payment

I have a Prestashop shop online and I'm integrating an Android APP with it, and to do payments I would want to shop the cart view and payment on a Webview inside the App. I've tried to found more information about cookies in Prestashop but the session cookie is encrypted and I don't know how to build it. Has anyone achieved to pay on Prestashop inside a WebView?

Comment: Did you achieved payments in the android app @Iluisu ? I am trying to build native app using prestashop web-service ....and i don't know how to do payments in the android app .....